# mongoose aggregate callback only return [object], where is the data`?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is my Model

```
const translateSchema = mongodb.Schema([{
  floor: {
    type: String
  },
  view: {
    type: String
  }
}]);

const TranslateModel = module.exports = mongodb.model('TranslateModel', translateSchema, 'translation');

module.exports.getTranslate = function(parms, callback){

  TranslateModel.aggregate([
      {
        $match:{$and:[{property:"ATL-D406"},{language:"gb"}]}
      },
      {
        $unwind:"$texts"
      },
      {
        $project:{"_id":0,"floor":"$texts.floor","view":"$texts.view"}
      }
    ],function(err, result) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);    
      console.log('Mongo Result 1: ' + result);
      console.log("Mongo Result 2: " + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
      callback(result);
  });

}
```

The aggregate works fine, in the console I get this:

```
Mongo Result1: [object Object]

Mongo Result2: [
    {
        "floor": "4th floor",
        "view": "Pool View (island)"
    }
]
```

So the fields are there, why wont it fit inside my Schema?

And when I try to send it back using callback(result); I get this error:

Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. ([object Object])

When I use getOne everything works fine, I get the result and can return it etc..  What am I not seeing?

Comment: When you do get one, do you also get fields like texts in result? As its not mentioned in mongoose schema above.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log("Mongo Result: " + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));`?

Comment: @chidam woah! - that showed the data:  Mongo Result: [
    {
        "floor": "4th floor",
        "view": "Pool View (island)"
    }
] --- so how do I get that into my Schema?

Comment: @MihirBhende Yes the result from the aggregate (when I run in robomongo) are two fields Mongo Result: [
    {
        "floor": "4th floor",
        "view": "Pool View (island)"
    }
] -- Now my problem is how I get that into my Schema.

Comment: @chridam btw what do the " ,4" mean in stringify?  I cant find that in the docs.

Comment: Ahh... identation spaces :)